# Azure Devops Changed Column Names But State Is Not Changing

Tags: azure-devops

I have been trying to switch to Azure Devops to manager our projects for quite a while now.
The latest hurdle is when viewing a Backlog item board.

The 'Planning Has Started' column does not work in our work flow, I have changed it to 'Paused' which means that items in that column have hit a road block and need attention.

But the 'State' when items are moved to that column still show 'Planning Has Started' and 'Paused' is not a option as a setting.

Where can I set/change the various States that are available?

I really have spent a good amount of time looking for this before asking here.

[image]

Comment: States are defined in the work item process template.

Comment: What about this issue, does the answer will help you? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Had a sick day and will check/update as soon as I am in the office later.  thank you

Comment: Take care of yourself, hope you get well soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current situation, we recommend you check your state mapping settings in your Borad. Please make sure you have mapped the right state to your columns 'Paused'.

[image]

Then, if you do not have the state 'Paused', you can go to the 'Organization settings --> Boards process --> Your own process --> New state' to create the new state 'Paused'.

[image]

Comment: you have a typo in the first sentence - "Borad".